# Man pays woman's fare on a bus and falls in love

Tags: identify-this-movie

I once saw a movie about a man who pays the fare of a woman on a bus. From there he falls in love with the girl. They then become friends, and indulge in many acts of sexual fetish in their relationship. The man eventually becomes tired of the relationship (because he wants to become famous), and asks the woman to break their relationship.

However, she says that she is ready to devote her entire life to him. He then decides to trick her, and they get on a plane. But before flying off, the man gets off the plane, leaving the girl inside, to get rid of her.

But she comes back (when he has an accident and is hospitalized), and tries to take revenge by pulling him out of the hospital bed. His backbone breaks and he becomes paralyzed for his entire life. She then starts her relationship with other men, letting him see her and suffer. And at the end, the man kills both her and him.

Comment: Just to be sure: you are not talking about [Breaking the Waves](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115751/), right?

Comment: No @nmat, I'm not talking about **Breaking the Waves**. Thanks for mentioning :).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The title of the movie is [Bitter Moon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104779/), which came out in 1992 in the UK and 1994 in the US. It was directed by [Roman Polanski](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000591/) and stars [Hugh Grant](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000424/) as Nigel.